# how to access date_joined column from each new account from management commands?

Tags: python, django

I am writing a custom management commands in Django for unverified users where each new account where it's longer than 24 hours without verifying the email confirmation, then flagged as `is_deleted=true`, my code looks like this , but however how can I access to `date_joined` of each new account?

```
User = get_user_model()

def handle(self, *args, **kwargs):
  now = datetime.datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo=utc)
  timediff = now - self.date_joined
  if User.objects.filter(is_superuser=True):
    pass
  else:
    if timediff.seconds / 3600 - 24 > 0:
      for user in User.objects.filter(date_joined__gt=timediff, signup_confirmation=0):
        user.is_deleted = True
        user.save()
        return True
    return False
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this. I guess its because of the typo.

```
for user in User.objects.filter(date_joined__gte=timediff, signup_confirmation=0):
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not run your SQL in a for loop this is very bad as you hit your database too many times and this slows down the db. Instead of your for loop just use django bulk_update,

```py
def handle(self, *args, **kwargs):
    now = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
    last_24_hours = now - datetime.timedelta(hours=24)
    User.objects.filter(
        date_joined__gte=last_24_hours,
        signup_confirmation=0).update(is_deleted=True)
    return True
```